# Injecting data object to window with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

**Background**

I am using Puppeteer to create some PDFs. I need to inject some data into the page when Puppeteer loads it.

**Problem**

I have tried using `evaluateOnNewDocument()` which was successful when using a `String` only. When I try with an `Object` it fails. I also tried with `evaluate()` and it fails regardless of what I pass in.

**Example**

```
// Works
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
           window.pdfData = {};
           window.pdfData = "Some String";
    });

// Does not work 
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
           window.pdfData = {};
           window.pdfData = data;
    });

// Fails
await page.evaluate(data => {
     window.pdfData = {};
     window.pdfData = data;
}, data);
```

I would like to access this object like this,

```
const data = window.pdfData;
```

**Question**

What is the proper way to pass a data object into window on a loaded Puppeteer page so that it can be accessed within the page to use the data client side?

Comment: What kind of data is in the `data` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Passing object to `evaluate`

You can pass data which will be serialized as JSON.

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(data => { // <-- pass as parameter
  window.pdfData = data; // <-- read it here
}, data); // <-- pass as argument
```

## Passing object to `evaluateOnNewDocument`

`evaluateOnNewDocument` works similarly to `evaluate`, except it will run whenever there is a new window/navigation/frame. This way the data will stay even if you navigate away to another page.

You can pass data and read inside the function.

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(data => {
  window.pdfData = data;
}, data);
```

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer and up voted you. Sorry I was out of town and just got back. I also got down voted 2 weeks after asking this question with no explanation. Very frustrating. Thanks for your help. The only thing I had to change was creating the object before assigning the data to it like this, `window.pdfData = {};`. Thanks a ton for your help. Hopefully we don't continue to get down votes without reason.